# Apps Script Error. Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run a function within a sheet. The data used for the calculations is from another sheet. I'm trying to open it by the sheet id and use sheet 1  to make the required calculations. I'm not able to get my range in sheet 1 though. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18UIbdc8Sw1zwc");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastCol= sheet.getLastColumn();

ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).getRange(1,30, lastRow).activate();

var data = sheet.getRange(1, 30, lastRow).getValues();
```

Comment: [Edit] to Quote the exact error (including line number). Format your code too.

Comment: Error: Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number).Line number 4

Comment: 1.Was that all  that the error said? 2.And which line in your code is line 4? Try removing `ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).getRange(1,30, lastRow).activate();`

Comment: Is there anyway I can make out which line the error is in if I'm running the function from a different speadsheet? 
Sorry I'm new to this!

Comment: Thanks I got it running! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're trying to do in this line: `ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).getRange(1,30, lastRow).activate();`

You don't need to set a sheet as active in order to call `getRange` on it. You already set `sheet` to be specifically the first sheet in the document when you called `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`. You should then be able to call `var data = sheet.getRange(1, 30, lastRow).getValues();` as you do in your last line, without that `setActiveSheet` line.

Comment: Thanks! It works without it! 
Also, Is there anyway I can make out which line the error is in if I'm running the function from a different spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks! I got it running! :)

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting my answer, if it solved your problem? Thanks :)